# Trying to add new record if it doesnt exist in an array

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, sequelize.js

I am writing a nodejs based script to take temperature readings from a raspberry pi and having some troubles with the Sequelize part where it adds the sensor to the database.

`sensor.list` is used by the ds18x20 library to get all of the sensors connected to the raspi. I need to iterate through the results of this list function, and if the `sensorId` doesn't exist in the database, i need to add it.

So far i have the following code, which retrieves the list of sensors, iterates over them and looks them up in the database..

```
sensor.list(function(e, sensors){
  logger.debug("Sensors Found:");
  logger.debug(sensors);
  for(var i=0; i < sensors.length;i++){
    db.Sensor.find({
      where: { sensorId: sensors[i] }
    }).success(function(s){
      if (!s){
        ##sensors[i] is undefined here
        logger.debug('Adding Sensor '+sensors[i]+' To the database as it doesn\'t exist!');
        db.Sensor.create({
          sensorId: sensors[i],
          name: sensors[i]
        });
      }else{
        Sensors.push(s);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that by the time the success callbacks starts triggering, i will have the value of `sensors.length`.

You may approach it like

```js
sensor.list(function(e, sensors){
  
  /* This function returns the function which should 
  execute after callback with presnt i bound to it */
  function GnBindCb(i) {
  
     return function(s) {
      if (!s){
        ##sensors[i] is undefined here
        logger.debug('Adding Sensor '+sensors[i]+' To the database as it doesn\'t exist!');
        db.Sensor.create({
          sensorId: sensors[i],
          name: sensors[i]
        });
      }else{
        Sensors.push(s);
      }
    };
  
  }
  
  
  logger.debug("Sensors Found:");
  logger.debug(sensors);
  for(var i=0; i < sensors.length;i++){
    db.Sensor.find({
      where: { sensorId: sensors[i] }
    }).success(GnBindCb(i)());
  }
  
  
});
```

For more inputs about this issue, you can refer [`this post on Stackoverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: thanks, i ended up using findOrCreate but your example and link provides some insight into scope.